# ASIO sound card that works in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, sound-cards, asio

I'm looking for an [ASIO sound card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output) which I would be using in both Windows and Linux (dual-boot). It has to work flawlessly in Windows, and I would prefer it to work fully in Linux as well. However, I can live with a card that has some features disabled in Linux, as long as basic playback and recording works, I don't have to install any proprietary drivers, it works reliably, and is hassle-free (i.e. no configuration to get regular sound working, and none of that "has to boot in Windows first before it works in Linux").

I would prefer a PCIe card, and although I would be using this mostly for playback, I also want recording to work. I'm using Debian. Price range: less than 150€.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too. Though I'd settle for any sound card that worked well on both Windows and Linux. I have been using the Soundblaster Live! 5.1 card for some time, and though it's a reasonable card, the sound quality leaves a little to be desired. Is ASIO a desirable standard for a sound card? I've read the Wikipedia page, but that didn't tell me much.

Comment: @FaheemMitha ASIO is probably not needed if you want to play games, listen to music, and that sort of thing. ASIO is needed if you need really low-latency sound on Windows, and a lot of music-making software requires an ASIO sound card to achieve sensible (low) latency. For example, if you use a MIDI keyboard to trigger sounds played by the computer, you need to get the sound out of the speakers very soon after you've hit a key. Otherwise, it will be quite hard to play, especially if you're playing with someone else (like in a band).

Comment: I was looking at the Xonar DX. See http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2014-11-04-asus-xonar-dx-soundcard-pcie-7-1-digital-out-dolby-eax-192khz-24bit-low-profile. Is that a ASIO card?

Comment: Actually, the similar D2X is listed as ASIO. See http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2014-08-02-asus-xonar-d2x-sound-card-pcie-7-1-digital-inout-dolby-dts-eax-192khz-24bit-asio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Asus Xonar D2X appears to fulfil your requirements.

Here are two links regarding Linux support:

http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2014-08-02-asus-xonar-d2x-sound-card-pcie-7-1-digital-inout-dolby-dts-eax-192khz-24bit-asio

and

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Asus

Amazon.de appears to list it for under 150€. E.g.

http://www.amazon.de/Asus-D2X-interne-Soundkarte-Digital/dp/B0011BC1FO/

It is also an ASIO sound card.